# Including All querystring parameters in Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, query-string

In my page i have

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("list", "menu", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <div>
           Show categories:
            @Html.DropDownList("groupName", (SelectList)ViewBag.groups)
            <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Show" />
        </div>
    }
```

Regarding the option the user choose i generate a list and the Querystring in my address going to be like :

```
localhost/menu/list?groupName=controlpanel
```

My problem is when i use HtmlActionLink for example :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Title", "List", new { foo = item.foo})
```

What i got in result is result is :

```
localhost/menu/List?foo=123
```

instead of :

```
 localhost/menu/List?foo=123&groupName=controlpanel
```

Am i missing something ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a built in solution, even though it seems to address exactly what you are looking for:

[ASP.NET MVC Build Url Based on Current Url](http://www.zvolkov.com/clog/2012/04/01/asp-net-mvc-build-url-based-on-current-url/)

Comment: Thank you.It seems it's the only way to handle it.By the way I'm using MvcPagedList which is smart enough to do the same when putting page links.

Answer (score 1):

To use ActionLink, you need to include all of the parameters you want to appear in the query string. The easiest thing I think would be is to add a GroupName property on your model (or in the ViewBag like your other sample). Then you can do this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Title", "List", new { foo = item.foo, groupName = Model.GroupName })
```

Comment: That's right but i want a general way in which works with multiple querystring parameters.